# X Window over SSH won't appear

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, x11, x11-forwarding

I have previously had some issue with MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keys so I have temporarily set host + to allow all connections open x windows locally (I am aware of the security flaw).

Now when I launch an application on the remote machine it seems to launch successfully without any errors but won't appear on my local machine, when I echo $DISPLAY it isn't set to localhost. Seems incredibly weird, where are my x windows sent to? How do I fix this?

Here is my debug:

```
$ firefox
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from *serverip* 55412
debug1: channel 3: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
```

The server is only available from my bosses IP so I have to proxy through him every time, maybe that's the issue. Do I have any other alternatives.

Comment: I've had success with `ssh -X` and `ssh -Y`.

Comment: I have tried both, when I bash appname it won't throw an error but wont appear on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use a VPN and run the browser locally - this will avoid any remote X issues. The easiest way to set up a VPN for this use-case is to just use `ssh`'s [built-in VPN support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN).

You can for example make all your network traffic go through the VPN - according to that page that is done with `ip route replace default via 10.0.0.1` (or whatever the IP is).

Comment: I need to run various apps, not just the browser.

Comment: No problem. The solution I suggested will work with any app, because it works at the kernel level.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ssh -X user@IPAddress`

Then from within the ssh connection, run `echo $DISPLAY`.
This will output something like `10.0`

Now set the DISPLAY variable as that value. For example, run `export DISPLAY=:10.0`

Now try running firefox via the ssh connection.

Also, make sure if the following lines exist in the system that you are trying to connect to in the file: **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

**X11Forwarding yes**

**X11DisplayOffset 10**

**X11UseLocalhost yes**

Comment: Says authentication failed, why would I route X to localhost? I am trying to view it remotely from my machine, not route the remote machine to itself.

Comment: You need to run this on your system to connect to the remote system using the remote system's IP address. Echoing the DISPLAY variable will show you the value of your system's display, not the remote's.